# Python 3 - need from exec() to return values

Tags: python, return, exec

I have a small problem with `exec()`. I have string from Kivy GUI which I need to execute and store values from the executed code.

```
class gui(BoxLayout):
    def proces(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.graf)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def graph(self):

        CodeInput=self.ids.codas
        Code=CodeInput.text
        x, y = [], []
        exec(Code)
        print(x,y) # empty list prints
        # then x y will serve for plotting a graph
```

---

This is a string inside the 'Code':

```
def values():
    x=np.linspace(0,3.14,100)
    y=np.sin(x)
    print(x) # of course works
    return x,y
x,y=values()
```

---

Everything WORKS except I cant get the values x,y from exec(Code). Its like exec() is totaly separate operation that can be started but cannot be entered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should call `exec` with a local namespace:

```
loc = {}
exec(Code, {}, loc)
x = loc['x']
y = loc['y']
```